# Not able to get all child elements from a modal window

Tags: c#, ui-automation

I am trying to get access to a checkbox present in the modal window.
And check- uncheck it by using UI-automation/uiacomwrapper.

I am able to do it, but in some application, it is failing.
For example, say Team Viewer. I am not able to get access to the checkbox present in the modal window.

```
var testi = win.GetWindowByName("TeamViewer");
        var child_win = win.GetChildWindow();
        var window = (AutomationElement)child_win.Element;

        var cb = window.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Start TeamViewer with Windows"));
```

it should return some value in cb, but it is returning null.
The same code is running fine with other windows form and WPF applications.
Only in case of Team Viewer, it is returning null.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUWWB.png)

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure here as I do not use Team Viewer.

NameProperty would find elements whose Name matches your input. Usually the name is something that makes sense to the programmer. You might have to iterate over the elements and pick one whose caption matches your query.

Comment: yes, I even tried that by using window.FindAll instead of window.FindFirst. But the return collection of elements does not contain checkbox. But when I use => element = AutomationElement.FromPoint(new System.Windows.Point((double)System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X, (double)System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y));  It is returning checkbox present at that location.